# How can I allow programmable key inputs in Processing?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement, processing

I am writing a Processing script and want to detect whether a key (using the `key` variable) is one of a set of keys chosen by the user ahead of time (say, in a settings JSON file or some other method). I used a switch/case statement to set this up, but it turns out I cannot use variables as case expressions.

I have used the `final` keyword to mark them as constants, and this works for those defined as direct variables, but not those stored inside an array.

Is there a way of doing this to avoid either using a long `if`/`elseif` statement or splitting the array into multiple variables?

In case that's not clear (pun not intended), this is my current code:

```
// constants
final char[] teamHotkeys  = {'b', 'y', 'p', 'o', 'r'};

final char animationHotkey = ' ';
final char doAllHotkey = 'a';

...

// keyPressed handler
void keyPressed(){
 float[] chartArea = {gridSizeHeight * 2, gridSizeHeight * 22, gridSizeWidth * 1, gridSizeWidth * 23};
 // check which key has been pressed
 switch (key){
   case teamHotkeys[0]:
     drawBar(0, chartArea);
     break;
   case teamHotkeys[1]:
     drawBar(1, chartArea);
     break;
   case teamHotkeys[2]:
     drawBar(2, chartArea);
     break;
   case teamHotkeys[3]:
     drawBar(3, chartArea);
     break;
   case teamHotkeys[4]:
     drawBar(4, chartArea);
     break;
   case animationHotkey:
     runAnimation();
     break;
   case doAllHotkey:
     showFinalScores();
     break;
 }
}
```

The compiler can access `animationHotkey` and `doAllHotkey` fine, now they are constants, but it can't access the indices of `teamHotkeys[]` as only the array is a constant, but its members could technically have changed, but the compiler doesnt' know that they never change.

Comment: *"but it turns out I cannot use variables as case expressions"* what do you mean?  Post the code showing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @zero298 - Looking back, I understand that what I said might be a little hard to understand. I'll add a code snippet, but basically I need to use a switch statement and put `case array_identifier[index]:`, but the compiler needs a constant or literal so it can know it at compile time. (I'm using Java mode, in case that makes a difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `if` statements. Sometimes the dumbest code is the best. It's the easiest to understand, and once it's written you can put it in a function somewhere and not really look at it very much.

But if you really want to avoid `if` statements, one approach you might take is to create a `HashMap` that maps character keys to runnable actions. Here's a very basic example:

```
HashMap<Character, Runnable> keyRunnableMap = new HashMap<Character, Runnable>();

void setup() {
  Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      println("A pressed.");
    }
  };

  Runnable bRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      println("B pressed.");
    }
  };

  keyRunnableMap.put('a', aRunnable);
  keyRunnableMap.put('b', bRunnable);
}

void draw() {
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyRunnableMap.containsKey(key)) {
    keyRunnableMap.get(key).run();
  }
}
```

This allows you to keep your `keyPressed()` logic very short, but it takes more code to set up. You could shorten this a little bit with Java 8 lambdas, but that won't work if you're using the current version of the Processing editor. I don't actually recommend this approach. Just stick with `if` statements.

**Edit:** You could also rely on the fact that behind the scenes, the `key` variable is a `char` type, which is actually a number. Lower-case `'a'` is the number `97`. More info [here](http://www.asciitable.com/). Here's an example:

```
Runnable[] runnableArray = new Runnable[2];

void setup() {
  Runnable aRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      println("A pressed.");
    }
  };

  Runnable bRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      println("B pressed.");
    }
  };

  runnableArray[0] = aRunnable;
  runnableArray[1] = bRunnable;
}

void draw() {
}

void keyPressed() {

  // a = 97, b = 98
  if(key >= 'a' && key <= 'b'){
    int index = key - 97;
    runnableArray[index].run();
  }
}
```

Again, I don't actually recommend this approach, as it's not any more readable than `if` statements.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say "Thanks" in comments, but this has clarified things. I was really just avoiding if statements because of DRY (lots of `else if key == hotkeys[n]`, though I could just set up a loop if I wanted to), but I think I'll go that way.

Comment: @Kieran You might consider mapping the `char` value to an `int` that you use in an array. Let me try to put together another example.

Comment: I went with a `default` which branches off to another method to have an `if` statement in a `for` loop to check for if it's a key in `teamHotkeys`

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C# a long switch is basically a HashMap, but in Java it is just... many if/else's, so I usually prefer HashMap when I can use it.

If you only want to know if your key is into a group (let's say, "teamHotkeys") you could use a `HashMap<Character, String>` or `HashMap<Character, KeyType>` (with KeyType as an enum), to map multiple keys to a same action. It still will be O(n) in the worst case, but since the keys are grouped it should be better than a lot of if/else's.

```
HashMap<Character, KeyType> keyTypePairs = new HashMap<Character, KeyType>();
switch(keyTypePairs.get(key)) {
    case teamHotkeys:
        // ...
        break;
}

enum KeyType { teamHotkeys, otherType1, otherType2 }
```

And that's all, it should work if I did understand the question.

EDIT: With a quick test I can say the space ocuppied by the HashMap is between 2.3 and 3.5 kilobytes in the worst case. About 300 entries = null reserved space, 120 (int)keys and KeyType (each enum uses an 4 or 8 byte address depending on the CPU). Is not THAT much, but I'll take it in acount if I was you. Also, I say 300 as an aproximation; I don't have 120 keys so it could be much less or much more.